# MSI x99 motherboard cannot detect nvme after clr CMOS

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, nvme

My Intel 600p nvme drive with Win 10 installed was working fine until I reset the BIOS.

I pressed the CLR CMOS button by accident when trying to plug in a cable.

Now the computer doesn't boot at all.

Going to the MSI BIOS, I can't find the NVME drive at all in boot or in storage.  M.2. shows "Not Detected."

I have the latest BIOS.  What could be the problem here?  Why can't the BIOS detect my Intel NVME SSD that already has Win 10 installed?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What cable did you plugin? Maybe you loosened the connection to the drive by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the CLR CMOS button should clear all the settings in BIOS.  If you bought the computer from a company, you could just call them to have them tell you the proper settings for the BIOS.